# How to pass a path of image as a prop in Gatsby in Gatsby-plugin-image

Tags: gatsby, gatsby-image, gatsby-plugin

I am trying to pass a path of an image as a prop to a component

Note: Both the component and the index page can access the image through the same path. It is not working when i pass the path as a prop

In the below code i have tried with both GatbsyImage and StaticImage tag both seems to fail

index.js

```
import React from "react";
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import '../styles/index.scss';
import Main from  '../Layouts/main';
import ImageOverlay from '../components/ImageOverlay';
import { StaticImage } from "gatsby-plugin-image"

function Home(){
  // Home page images
  return (
    <Main >
    <section className="home_page">
      <ImageOverlay path="../images/home/places/portblair.png"> </ImageOverlay>
    </section>
    </Main>
  )
}

export default Home
```

components/ImageOverlay.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { GatsbyImage, StaticImage } from "gatsby-plugin-image"
const ImageOverlay = ({path}) =>{
    return(

      <div>
          <GatsbyImage image={path}></GatsbyImage>
          <StaticImage src={path}></StaticImage>
      </div> 
  
    )
}
export default ImageOverlay;
```

I used GatsbyImage and StaticImage just incase to check

Thanks for the help in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't use outer `props` on `StaticImage`, it's a [known restriction](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-image/#restrictions-on-using-staticimage):

> **Restrictions on using `StaticImage`**
>
> There are a few technical restrictions to the way you can pass props
> into `StaticImage`. Most importantly, you can’t use any of the parent
> component’s props. For more information, refer to the [Gatsby Image
> plugin reference guide](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/built-in-components/gatsby-plugin-image/#restrictions-on-using-staticimage). If you find yourself wishing you could use a
> prop passed from a parent for the image `src` then it’s likely that you
> should be using a dynamic image.

And extending the referenced guide:

> ```
> // ⚠️ Doesn't work
> export function Logo({ logo }) {
>   // You can't use a prop passed into the parent component
>   return <StaticImage src={logo}>
> }
> ```

The solution, if you want to use `StaticImage` is to use the static approach, appending the `src` directly:

```
import React from 'react';
import { GatsbyImage, StaticImage } from "gatsby-plugin-image"
const ImageOverlay = ({path}) =>{
    return(

      <div>
          <StaticImage src={`../images/home/places/portblair.png`}></StaticImage>
      </div> 
  
    )
}
export default ImageOverlay;
```

If you want to use `GatsbyImage`, you will need to query your image to get the proper data:

```
import { graphql } from "gatsby"
import { GatsbyImage, getImage } from "gatsby-plugin-image"

function Home({ data }) {
 const image = getImage(data.blogPost.avatar)
 return (
   <section>
     <GatsbyImage image={image} alt={data.blogPost.author} />
     <p>{data.blogPost.body}</p>
   </section>
 )
}

export const pageQuery = graphql`
 query {
   blogPost(id: { eq: $Id }) {
     title
     body
     author
     avatar {
       childImageSharp {
         gatsbyImageData(
           width: 200
           placeholder: BLURRED
           formats: [AUTO, WEBP, AVIF]
         )
       }
     }
   }
 }
`
```

*Note: of course, adapt the snippet to your needs but get the idea*

If you want to use a dynamic image, you are forced to make a GraphQL query to allow Gatsby and their transformers to parse and resolve the image. You can use the bunch of available filters to create a specific query for your image using as well as the `relativePath` and the `absolutePath`, test the query at `localhost:8000/___graphql`.

Answer (score 0):

While you can't pass the `src` for `StaticImage` as a string from the parent component you can still pass a `StaticImage`:

Component

```js
…
const ImageOverlay = ({staticImage}) =>{
  return <div>
    {staticImage('myClass')}
  </div> 
}
export default ImageOverlay;
```

Parent (consumer)

```js
…
const ImageOverlay = ({path}) =>{
  return <div>
    <ImageOverlay
      staticImage={className => <StaticImage
        className={className}
        src="../images/home/places/portblair.png"
        alt="Portblair"
    />}
  </div> 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Somethimes when you pass a image path as a prop to a component for **GatsbyImage and StaticImage** tag. and did not show image has some reasons.

1. image path issue.

> ```
> my-gatsby-project/
> │
> ├── src/
> │   ├── components/
> │   │   ├── Image_overlay/
> │   │       ├── ImageOverlay.js
> │   │       └── (other components...)
> │   │
> │   ├── images/
> │   │   ├── image.jpg
> │   │   └── (other images...)
> │   │
> │   ├── pages/
> │   │   ├── index.js
> │   │   └── (other pages...)
> │   │
> │   └── (other project files...)
> │
> ├── gatsby-config.js
> ├── package.json
> ├── (other project files...)
> ```

when your using image in src/pages/index.js you will use image path as

```
../images/image.jpg
```

while in ImageOverlay.js file you will use as

```
../../images/image.jpg
```

This can be solve if you are using absolute path in you project then in both files you will be able to access image by this path

```
images/image.jpg
```

2. You can't use props on StaticImage as there are a few technical restrictions. about that restrictions you can read [this](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/built-in-components/gatsby-plugin-image/#restrictions-on-using-staticimage)

And in case if you are getting image from DB as a query then you can pass that as a prop and access it in a component using **GatsbyImage** tag.