# (Gatsby) How to pass image source as a prop in MDX component

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I'm trying to create a `Figure` component in which I pass the `img src` along with other data.

I realize it's not straightforward—e.g., [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66759909/how-to-pass-a-path-of-image-as-a-prop-in-gatsby-in-gatsby-plugin-image)—but I thought it would work fine with normal HTML `img` tags.

The image is not displaying. Does that mean that [this limitation](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/blog/mdx-embedded-gatsby-image/) also applies to HTML `img` tags within components?

If this is the case, I guess I indeed ought to use Gatsby's dynamic images. How would I do this in a static query (nonpage component)? [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55122752/reusable-gatsby-image-component-with-dynamic-image-sources) had me believing it isn't possible—or at least a hack?

### The component inside MDX documents:

```
<Figure 
  image=""
  size=""
  caption=""
  credits=""
/>
```

### `Figure.js`:

```
import * as React from "react"

const Figure = ({ image, size, caption, credits }) => {
  return (
    <figure className={size}>
      <img src={image} alt={caption} />
      <figcaption>
        <span>{caption}</span>
        <span>{credits}</span>
      </figcaption>
    </figure>
  )
}

export default Figure
```

### `articlePostTemplate.js`

```
import * as React from "react"
import { graphql } from "gatsby"
import { MDXRenderer } from "gatsby-plugin-mdx"
import Layout from "../components/layout.js"
import Seo from "../components/seo.js"

const PostTemplate = ({ data, location }) => {
  let post = data.mdx

  return (
    <Layout location={location}>
      <Seo
        title={post.frontmatter.title}
        description={post.frontmatter.lead}
        date={post.frontmatter.computerDate}
      />
      <article className="post">
        <header className="post" id="intro">
          <p className="date">
            <time dateTime={post.frontmatter.computerDate}>{post.frontmatter.humanDate}</time>
          </p>
          <h1 itemprop="headline">{post.frontmatter.title}</h1>
          <p className="lead">{post.frontmatter.lead}</p>
        </header>
        <section className="post" id="body-text">
          <MDXRenderer data={data}>{post.body}</MDXRenderer>
        </section>
      </article>
    </Layout>
  )
}

export default PostTemplate

export const pageQuery = graphql`
  query PostBySlug(
    $id: String!
  ) {
    site {
      siteMetadata {
        title
      }
    }
    mdx(id: { eq: $id }) {
      id
      excerpt(pruneLength: 160)
      body
      frontmatter {
        title
        computerDate: date(formatString: "YYYY-MM-DD")
        humanDate: date(formatString: "D. MMMM YYYY", locale: "nb")
        hook
        type
        lead
        featuredImage {
          childImageSharp {
            fluid(maxWidth: 800) {
              ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

### `gatsby-config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  …
  },
  plugins: [
    `gatsby-plugin-image`,
    `gatsby-plugin-sitemap`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-mdx`,
      options: {
        extensions: [`.md`, `.mdx`],
        gatsbyRemarkPlugins: [
          {
            resolve: `gatsby-remark-images`,
            options: {
              maxWidth: `900000000000`,
              linkImagesToOriginal: false,
              backgroundColor: `none`,
            },
          },
          {
            resolve: `gatsby-remark-responsive-iframe`,
            options: {
              wrapperStyle: `margin-bottom: 1.07var(--line-length)`,
            },
          },
          `gatsby-remark-prismjs`,
          `gatsby-remark-copy-linked-files`,
          `gatsby-remark-smartypants`,
          {
            resolve: `gatsby-remark-autolink-headers`,
              options: {
                icon: false,
                itemprop: `heading`,
                maintainCase: false,
                removeAccents: true,
                elements: [`h2`, `h3`, `h4`],
              },
          }
        ],
      },
    },
    …
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `content`,
        path: `${__dirname}/content/`,
      }
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        path: `${__dirname}/src/data`,
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        path: `${__dirname}/src/images`,
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        path: `${__dirname}/src/pages/`,
      }
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `journalistikk`,
        path: `${__dirname}/content/journalism/`,
      }
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `discussion`,
        path: `${__dirname}/content/discussion/`,
      }
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `photography`,
        path: `${__dirname}/content/photography/`,
      }
    },
    `gatsby-transformer-sharp`,
    `gatsby-plugin-sharp`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-manifest`,
      options: {
        name: `Gatsby Starter Blog`,
        short_name: `GatsbyJS`,
        start_url: `/`,
        background_color: `#ffffff`,
        display: `minimal-ui`,
        icon: `src/images/gatsby-icon.png`,
      },
    },
    `gatsby-plugin-react-helmet`,
  ],
}
```

### `gatsby-node.js`

```
const path = require(`path`)
const { createFilePath } = require(`gatsby-source-filesystem`)

exports.createPages = async ({ graphql, actions, reporter }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions

  const articlePostTemplate = path.resolve(`./src/templates/articlePostTemplate.js`)

  const result = await graphql(
    `
      {
        allMdx(
          sort: { fields: [frontmatter___date], order: ASC }
          limit: 1000
        ) {
          nodes {
            id
            frontmatter {
              title
              computerDate: date(formatString: "YYYY-MM-DD")
              humanDate: date(formatString: "D. MMMM YYYY", locale: "nb")
            }
            fields {
              slug
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `
  )

  if (result.errors) {
    reporter.panicOnBuild(
      `There was an error loading your blog posts`,
      result.errors
    )
    return
  }

  const posts = result.data.allMdx.nodes

  if (posts.length > 0) {
    posts.forEach((post, index) => {
      [index + 1].id

      createPage({
        path: post.fields.slug,
        component: articlePostTemplate,
        context: {
          id: post.id
        },
      })
    })
  }
}

exports.onCreateNode = ({ node, actions, getNode }) => {
  const { createNodeField } = actions

  if (node.internal.type === `Mdx`) {
    const value = createFilePath({ node, getNode })

    createNodeField({
      name: `slug`,
      node,
      value,
    })
  }
}

exports.createSchemaCustomization = ({ actions }) => {
  const { createTypes } = actions

 
  createTypes(`
    type SiteSiteMetadata {
      author: Author
      siteUrl: String
      social: Social
    }

    type Author {
      name: String
      summary: String
    }

    type Social {
      twitter: String
      instagram: String
      mail: String
    }

    type MarkdownRemark implements Node {
      frontmatter: Frontmatter
      fields: Fields
    }

    type Frontmatter {
      title: String
      description:  String
      date: Date @dateformat
    }

    type Fields {
      slug: String
    }
  `)
}
```

### `layout.js`

```
import * as React from "react"
import { MDXProvider } from "@mdx-js/react"
import { Link } from "gatsby"
import DWChart from "react-datawrapper-chart"
import Header from "./Header"
import Footer from "./Footer"
import Figure from "./Figure"

const shortcodes = { Link, DWChart, Figure }

export default function Layout({ children }) {
  return (
    <div className="layout-wrapper">
      <Header />
      <main>
        <MDXProvider components={shortcodes}>{children}</MDXProvider>
      </main>
      <Footer />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hat tip to [Ferran](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5585371/ferran-buireu) for helpful guidance.

After more research, I revised my solution—

### `articleTemplate.js`

```
/* shortcodes */

const ArticleTemplate = ({ data, location }) => {
  let post = data.mdx

  return (
    <Layout location={location}>
      <Seo
        title={post.frontmatter.title}
        description={post.frontmatter.lead}
        date={post.frontmatter.computerDate}
      />
      <article className="article">
        <p className="date">
          <time dateTime={post.frontmatter.computerDate}>{post.frontmatter.humanDate}</time>
        </p>
        <h1 itemprop="headline">{post.frontmatter.title}</h1>
        <p className="lead" itemprop="introduction">{post.frontmatter.lead}</p>
        <MDXProvider components={shortcodes}>
          <MDXRenderer
            data={post.frontmatter.thumbnail}
            localImages={post.frontmatter.embeddedImagesLocal}
          >
            {post.body}
          </MDXRenderer>
        </MDXProvider>
      </article>
    </Layout>
  )
}

export default ArticleTemplate

export const pageQuery = graphql`
  query ArticleBySlug($id: String!) {
    site {
      siteMetadata {
        title
      }
    }
    mdx(id: {eq: $id}) {
      id
      excerpt(pruneLength: 160)
      body
      frontmatter {
        title
        computerDate: date(formatString: "YYYY-MM-DD")
        humanDate: date(formatString: "D. MMMM YYYY", locale: "nb")
        hook
        type
        lead
        thumbnail {
          childImageSharp {
            gatsbyImageData(
              layout: FULL_WIDTH
            )
          }
        }
        embeddedImagesLocal {
          childImageSharp {
            gatsbyImageData
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

### `figure.js`

```
import * as React from "react"
import { GatsbyImage, getImage } from 'gatsby-plugin-image'

const Figure = ({ source, size, caption, credit }) => {
  return (
    <figure className={size}>
      <GatsbyImage image={getImage(source)} alt={caption} />
      <figcaption>
        <span>{caption}</span>
        <span>{credit}</span>
      </figcaption>
    </figure>
  );
}

export default Figure
```

### `index.mdx`

```
---
…
thumbnail: "thumb.jpeg"
embeddedImagesLocal:
  - "first.jpeg"
  - "second.jpeg"
---

<Figure
  source={(props.localImages [0])} <!-- first image; second image would be `[1]` -->
  size="I'm a `className`"
  caption="I'm a caption"
  photographer="I'm a name."
/>
```

(Marking this as the solution as it's the most helpful for anyone looking to do this in the future. It also shows how to query for embedded images and featured images—at the same time.)

Comment: MDXRenderer is no longer present--children is already a rendered node. Have you adapted this pattern to the latest gatsby? If so, how?

Comment: Got it. Going forward, you can put your front matter into a React Context, then in your image component, read the frontmatter image data (as shown above) from said context, and pass directly into GatsbyImage.

Answer (score 3):

The limitation you mention in [How to pass a path of image as a prop in Gatsby in Gatsby-plugin-image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66759909/how-to-pass-a-path-of-image-as-a-prop-in-gatsby-in-gatsby-plugin-image) only applies to `StaticImage` + dynamic `props` data (with a dynamic source), meaning that the component that returns a `StaticImage` cannot receive the `src` as a `props`, because all the `props` of `StaticImage` needs to be statically analyzed.

In other words, your MDX can receive a `src` to be used in a `<img>` tag or you can use `GatsbyImage` component if properly configured.

Keep in mind that the query that will fetch `GatsbyImage` data (`childImageSharp`, `gatsbyImageData`, etc) must be placed in a top-level component (pages) if using a [page query](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/querying-data/page-query/) or in a [`useStaticQuery`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/querying-data/use-static-query/) hook if used elsewhere.

The approach in both scenarios (using `<img>` or `GatsbyImage`) is similar. You need to:

- Provide your image sources in your markdown file
- Query those images using a page query or `useStaticQuery` to provide to your `MDXProvider` the queried image `props`. Using the blog example:

  ```
    <MDXProvider>
      <MDXRenderer data={data}/>
    </MDXProvider>
  ```

  `data` stands for your queried data in a GraphQL page query or `useStaticQuery`. Without knowing your data structure I haven't add the GraphQL part because I do not know the nodes available.
- At this point, your `MDXProvider` holds the images data (all from your markdown files), you just need to provide it to your `GatsbyImage` or `Figure` component:

  ```
  // some.mdx 

  import Figure from 'path/to/figure/component';

  ## Post Body

  Lorem ipsum dolor...

  <Figure img={props.data} />
  ```

  As you can see, I lift all props to `Figure` just to allow to debug (using console.logs() for example) to see the available props there like:

  ```
  const Figure = (props) => {
     console.log(props);
     return (
       <div>I will be a figure in a future</div>
     )
  }

  export default Figure
  ```

  In that way, you will be able to pass to `Figure` something like `img={props.someNode.frontmatter.imageNodeSource}`.

  Again, without knowing your data structure is like a pie in the sky but get the idea.

Comment: Hi, thanks! I find this very difficult—isn't `props` unnecessary in this case, since I'm using curly brackets within the parentheses? As for the images: do I need to provide each image source in the MDX document's frontmatter? I've added more code to show the context.

Comment: The key part is lifting page query props (queried `data`) from your `PostTemplate` in your `MDXProvider` using `  <MDXProvider><MDXRenderer data={data}>{post.body}</MDXProvider>` or similar. In that case, you will have `data` (which holds your images sources from the `frontmatter` and `featuredImage`) available in your MDX, where you can use a `GatsbyImage` or a `<img>` tag

Comment: Does that mean I'll have to list the images under frontmatter for each MDX document in which I want to use this component? And do I have to add a `staticQuery` to `Figure.js`? I added `layout.js` above as well—in which I use the `MDXProvider` and the `data` you mentioned. (EDIT: I meant to say I added `data` to the template component, which is wrapped with the layout component.)

Comment: It will depend on your structure. You don't need to use `staticQuery` or `useStaticQuery` because you are already fetching a GraphQL structure to use along with `GatsbyImage`. In your `PostTemplate`  you are already using a page query. You only need to pass the image data in your MDX using props and use there the `GatsbyImage` as the tutorial shows `<GatsbyImage alt='some alt text' image={getImage(props...)} />`. In addition, you are  repeating the `MDXProvider` in your `Layout`. Use it only once.