# How to embed images in frontmatter with gatsby-plugin-mdx v4?

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, gatsby-plugin, gatsby-plugin-mdx

A while back I followed [this tutorial](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/blog/mdx-embedded-gatsby-image/) to implement image embeds in MDX posts. See [this query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71944655/gatsby-how-to-pass-image-source-as-a-prop-in-mdx-component) on Stack Overflow for context as well.

A v3 example template using this:

```js
/*  Post.jsx @ gatsby-plugin-mdx v3 */
import React from "react"
import { graphql } from "gatsby"
import { MDXRenderer } from "gatsby-plugin-mdx"
import Layout from "@layouts/Layout"
import { postContainer } from "@modules/Post.module.scss"

export default function DefaultPostTemplate({ data, location }) {
  const post = data.mdx

  return (
    <Layout location={location} title={post.frontmatter.title} description={post.frontmatter.lead}>
      <article className={postContainer}>
        <MDXRenderer thumbnail={post.frontmatter.thumbnail} embedded={post.frontmatter.embedded}>
      {post.body}
    </MDXRenderer>
      </article>
    </Layout>
  )
}

export const data = graphql`
  query ($id: String!) {
    mdx(id: { eq: $id }) {
      id
      body
      frontmatter {
        key
        title
        computerDate: date(formatString: "YYYY-MM-DD")
        humanDate: date(formatString: "D. MMMM YYYY", locale: "nn")
        enHumanDate: date(formatString: "MMMM D, YYYY", locale: "en")
        lead
        label
        subtitle
        embedded {
          childImageSharp {
            gatsbyImageData
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

As you can see, I passed the `embedded` property to the `MDXProvider` component.

However, with the [`gatsby-plugin-mdx`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-mdx/) v4 setup, I'm not sure how to do this—

```js
/*  Post.jsx @ gatsby-plugin-mdx v4 */
import React from "react"
import { graphql } from "gatsby"
import Layout from "@layouts/Layout"
import { postContainer } from "@modules/Post.module.scss"

export default function DefaultPostTemplate({ data, children }) {
  const post = data.mdx

  return (
    <Layout title={post.frontmatter.title} description={post.frontmatter.lead}>
      <article className={postContainer}>
        {children}
      </article>
    </Layout>
  )
}

export const data = graphql`
  query ($id: String!) {
    mdx(id: { eq: $id }) {
      frontmatter {
        key
        title
        computerDate: date(formatString: "YYYY-MM-DD")
        humanDate: date(formatString: "D. MMMM YYYY", locale: "nn")
        lead
        label
        subtitle
        embedded {
          childImageSharp {
            gatsbyImageData
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

How can I embed images as frontmatter with the new setup?

Answer (score 1):

I've also been struggling with this since v4. Here's what I found:

The graphql query result in your template file is accessible from within the MDX file via `props.data.mdx`

So in your case you could use `GatsbyImage` inside your mdx to render your image as follows (make sure this is placed below your frontmatter)

```
import { getImage, GatsbyImage } from "gatsby-plugin-image";

<GatsbyImage
  alt="alt text"
  image={getImage(props.data.mdx.frontmatter.embedded)}/>
```